# How to share a single Directive across multiple modules in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As far as I know about AngularJS, this is one of the interesting libraries out today. I am slowly understanding the Angular power, and I am seriously loving it. I have a few doubts and I hope I will get them clarified. Even after some background work, I am unable to understand how they can be done

1. For example I have a module in my App and I have directives written for it, And I want to add few more modules to my app and also want to reuse existing directives written for another module. How I can achieve that. Not only modules that applies to filters, config etc..
2. Can I have sub modules defined inside a Module?
3. How can I add a controller to an element dynamically, it should not be static, i.e through html markup `ng-controller`.
4. If I want to share a thing across all modules how can I do that.. For example I have a variable defined outside of all modules in my app and I just want to access them inside modules.. Is that possible, I have this doubt because it completely works on individual scopes, shared scope and rootScope etc..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mind 'marking' one of the answers :)

Comment: @Shreyas Thanks. I forgot :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Q: For example I have a module in my App and I have directives written
>   for it, And I want to add few more modules to my app and also want to
>   reuse existing directives written for another module. How I can
>   achieve that. Not only modules that applies to filters, config etc..

When you declare a module, you specify its dependencies. So if you have a directive like this:

```js
angular.module( 'moduleA', [] )

.directive( 'myDirective', function () {
  // ...
});
```

You can require that module from another module:

```js
angular.module( 'moduleB', [ 'moduleA' ] );
```

The array argument to `angular.module` is a list of dependencies.

> Q: Can I have sub modules defined inside a Module?

Modules are technically all independent, but it's super common to fake it. So we can define `moduleA` with it's "submodules" like so:

```js
angular.module( 'moduleA.one', [] );
angular.module( 'moduleA.two', [] );

angular.module( 'moduleA', [
  'moduleA.one',
  'moduleA.two'
]);
```

And it's clear to the developer/reader that `moduleA.one` and `moduleA.two` are part of `moduleA`, but also anytime another module depends on `moduleA`, its two submodules will be included as well.

But technically, these are all independent, so `moduleB` could also require `moduleA.two` if it wanted to do so.

> Q: How can I add a controller to an element dynamically, it should not be
>   static, i.e through html markup ng-controller.

This is probably not a good idea. The "view" is the official record. What's your use case?

> Q: If I want to share a thing across all modules how can I do that.. For
>   example I have a variable defined outside of all modules in my app and
>   I just want to access them inside modules.. Is that possible, I have
>   this doubt because it completely works on individual scopes, shared
>   scope and rootScope etc..

I am not sure I understand what you're asking. But when you define something in a module, you can access it from any other just by requiring it, as discussed above. But in an AngularJS app, there should be *anything* "outside of all modules" - everything should be in a module because otherwise it'ts defined in the global scope (e.g. `window`) and that's just bad practice.

---

To get a better understanding of how modules can be structured to great benefit, check out my `ngBoilerplate` kickstarter: http://ngbp.github.io/ngbp/. The module structure is specifically designed for code reuse and demonstrates many of these concepts in practice.

Feel free to elaborate on any of these and I will revise the responses.

Comment: Sensible answer dude.. Can you please provide any example for first answer.

Comment: In the `ngBoilerplate` I linked, the ["#/home" route](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/home/home.js) makes use of the `titleService`, which is defined in [its own module](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate/blob/master/src/components/titleService/titleService.js), as well as the `plusOne` directive, also defined in [its own module](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate/blob/master/src/components/plusOne/plusOne.js).

Comment: Thanks for explaining things with fake 'submodules'

Answer (score 5):

### The easiest way

The easiest way is to add all sharable directives and other parts to **ng** module.

```
angular
    .module("ng")
    .directive("myDirective", function() {
        ...
    })
    .filter("MyFilter", function() {
        ...
    });
```

This is the easiest way (a kind of *set and forget*) as you can easily just drop your directive script to your HTML and forget about it while developing new modules that naturally also require it.

### What else is good about this technique

Why is adding shareable stuff to **ng** module sensible? Because you may have simple pages in your app that don't define a particular **ngApp** module, but rather just set `ng-app` on  HTML/BODY and run inline angular directives only.

When you add your directive to `ng` module, these pages can also use your directive.

```
<html>
    <body ng-app>
        <div my-directive>
        ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cons with this technique?

Comment: I cannot restrict this directive to not be included in some modules.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a div at the beginning of your app so that its scope will be as large as you need it?

```
<div ng-controller="uberController as uber">

    ....

    other controllers and html code here

    ....
</div>
```

Anything inside the uber div may use the uber controller.