# How to define a global directive that can work like ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The most related question I can find on SO is "[How to share a single Directive across multiple modules in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190408/how-to-share-a-single-directive-across-multiple-modules-in-angularjs/)". But I need something a little different. I need something that can work more or less like ng-model. The page does not need to have a named `ng-app`.

Here is the real problem I want to solve:
I would like to define some template as samples that shows good accessibility. For example, the label for a required form field, should have arterisk (*). However, I don't want to force the users to define a named module in the JS file. Instead, they can just add `ng-app`(without name) to the `html` or `body` tag and include my JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Your directive(s) is/are defined in an Angular module.  I believe you have two choices to load such a module:

1. put `ng-app="myModule"` on an HTML element
2. [manual bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap), hence no `ng-app`

Answer (score 0):

You can add your directive directly to the `ng` module:

```
angular.module("ng")
    .directive("myDirective", function() {
        ...
})
```

But beware of potential name conflicts with new directives introduced by the angular team.